# PHP Sorting array alphabetically and numerically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

let's say I have array of iPhone models `['iPhone 11', 'iPhone 5', 'iPhone XS', 'iPhone 12']` which needs to be sorted in this mean `['iPhone 12', 'iPhone 11', 'iPhone 5', 'iPhone XS']`. What I have tried is using native sorting (p. g. sort()) functions or have tried direct orderBy from DB but all the solutions gave me this output `['iPhone 11', 'iPhone 12', 'iPhone 5', 'iPhone XS']`. Do anyone has some solution/idea how it should be done? I am getting quite frustrated after all tries.

Comment: your sorting is not automatable. Its not alphabetical or numeric. You must implement your sorting function

Comment: If I understood correctly, this could be generalized as always place numerical models first and textual after, with ASC and DESC controlling the order of the numerical/alphabetical sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You need [usort function](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php). For example,

```
function getPhoneModel($phoneName) {
  $regex = "/iPhone (.+)$/";
  preg_match($regex, $phoneName, $matches);
  $model = $matches[1];
  if ($model === 'XS') {
    $model = 1;
  }
  return intval($model);
}
    
$phones = ['iPhone 11', 'iPhone 5', 'iPhone XS', 'iPhone 12'];
usort($phones, function($phoneNameA, $phoneNameB) {

    $a = getPhoneModel($phoneNameA);
    $b = getPhoneModel($phoneNameB);
    if ($a > $b) {
        return (-1);
    } elseif ($a < $b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

print_r($phones);
```

This will result as

```
Array
(
    [0] => iPhone 12
    [1] => iPhone 11
    [2] => iPhone 5
    [3] => iPhone XS
)
```

Comment: This is fine as long as `XS` is the only possible textual model. If `SE` entered the combination, your algorithm would no longer work.

Comment: @El_Vanja I thought that author might wish to manually define rules of sorting alphabetical models. Maybe by year of release. In that case my method will fit better. Anyways, it's up to author, we gave him all information he needed :)

Answer (score 0):

The task is not described precisely enough.

I think it's even more complicated than in @El_Vanja's comment.I'm trying to be specific.

- The models have a model name and a type, separated by a space.
- The model names (here only iPhone) should be sorted alphabetically in
  ascending order.
- The numeric type how 11 takes precedence over    letters how XS.
- If the type is numeric, the order is descending.
- In the other case the type is sorted in ascending order.

For this task I expanded the sample array.

```
$in = ['ax A', 'iPhone 11', 'iPhone 5', 'iPhone XS', 'iPhone 12', 'master 6', 'ax Z', 'ax B','xphone'];
```

The solution is made with usort and a special sorting function.

```
function specialSort($a,$b){
  list($aModel,$aTyp) = explode(' ',$a.' ');
  list($bModel,$bTyp) = explode(' ',$b.' ');

  return $aModel <=> $bModel
   ?: (int)$bTyp <=> (int)$aTyp
   ?: $aTyp      <=> $bTyp
  ;
}

usort($in,'specialSort')
```

Test Output:

```
echo implode(' | ',$in);
//ax A | ax B | ax Z | iPhone 12 | iPhone 11 | iPhone 5 | iPhone XS | master 6 | xphone
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to user

```
array_multisort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Oh, thanks. I havent tried this simplicity. But one more thing, is it possible to sort it in reversed order with some native function? I mean to have it from 12 to lower models and then XS etc.

Comment: How is this related to the question? There is no mention of multiple arrays or an example of a multidimensional array.